# dropping duplicates across two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`), and I wish to drop observations in `df2` that are in `df1` on a one-to-one basis. For example,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[13,14,15,16], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

df1
   A   B   C   D 
0  1   2   3   4      
1  1   2   3   4     
2  5   6   7   8     
3  9  10  11  12     

df2

    A   B   C   D 
0  13  14  15  16      
1   1   2   3   4     
2   1   2   3   4
```

For this, I'd like both 1 and 2 (index) observations in `df2` dropped because they exist in `df1` as well. So, any observation in `df2` should be dropped as long as there's an identical observation in `df1` to match it. So, if `df1` were to be:

```
df1
   A   B   C   D 
0  1   2   3   4      
1  5   6   7   8     
2  9  10  11  12
```

only one observation in `df2` (either 1 or 2) should be dropped (because there's only one identical counterpart in `df1`).

I have tried using `.duplicated()` or `groupby` to find number of unique observations, but no luck so far. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use a left `pd.merge` with `indicator` as true. But first, you'll need to get a row count by group as you only want to remove on a one-on-one basis.

```
# Init
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[13,14,15,16], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

# get number of rows within group
cols_ = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
df2['count'] = df2.groupby(cols_).cumcount()+1
df1['count'] = df1.groupby(cols_).cumcount()+1

# merge and filter
out = df2.merge(df1, on=cols_ + ['count'], how='left', indicator=True)
out=out[out['_merge'] == 'left_only']
out[cols_]
```

Output:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  13  14  15  16
```

If instead df1 =

```
df1
   A   B   C   D 
0  1   2   3   4      
1  5   6   7   8     
2  9  10  11  12
```

the output is:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  13  14  15  16
2   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, based on [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter([tuple(row) for row in df1.values])
c2 = Counter([tuple(row) for row in df2.values])
pd.DataFrame((c2-c1).elements(), columns=df2.columns)
```

---

Another possible solution, based on [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

def drop_match(df1, df2, i, row): 
    # drops the 2 matching rows in the 2 dfs.
    # i, row are, respectively, the index and row of df2 to be
    # compared with the rows of df1.
    for j, rw in df1.iterrows():
        if (row == rw.values).all():
            df1.drop(j, axis=0, inplace=True)
            df2.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)
            break
    
    return df1, df2

reduce(lambda d, y: drop_match(d[0], d[1], y[0], y[1]), 
       [[i, x.values] for i, x in df1.iterrows()], [df2, df1])[0]
```

---

Output:

First example:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  13  14  15  16
```

Second example:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  13  14  15  16
2   1   2   3   4
```